# Applying backgrounds to TikZ scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, scoping

I have problems creating a background for a `scope` envionment
Here is part of the code I used for a `beamer` slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]    

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate[shift={(4.5cm,-3.5cm)}] (Anchor) at (current page.north west);

\only<2>{\begin{scope}[shift={(Anchor)},/tikz/background rectangle/.style={
        fill=yellow,
        draw=black
    },show background rectangle]
\draw[thin,->] (0,0) node (origin) [below] {$0$} -- (0,1) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$};
\draw[thin,->] (-1,0) node (xaxisL) {} -- (1,0) node (xaxisR) [right] {$x$};
\end{scope} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edited for clarification:
Because of problem of background when **overlay** specification is active, i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, show background...]`, This is the reason why I want to see if there is a simple way to put the background inside a `scope` environment. There isn't unfortunately and one have to draw their own background within `scope` it seems.

Comment: There is nothing being drawn on the first slide. Can you please draw everything like 2 scopes and describe the problem as *...I want the first scope disappear on slide x and make the scope 2 background appear as y color....* even include an image. Right now, only you know what you want to do and it's too localized for us to get a hold of it.

Comment: @percusse Thanks, well I nailed the problem, but still no solution. Basically, the BACKGROUND tool in tikz does not work with overlays. If overlay option is used, i.e. _\begin{tikzpicture}[**overlay**,show background rectangle,...]_ the background fills the whole page.  Without the overlay option I cannot position the subplot in the slide arbitrarily.

Comment: I found out how to use pgfonlayer to make my own background. Thanks anyway

Comment: I wish I could understand what your problem was. I will delete my answer and can you please wrap up your solution with a small working code. Others can benefit from this.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, I am trying to 'answer my own question' but the system won't let me for another 6 hours :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I put a custom `pgfonlayer` background  on every `scope`. This relinquish the need to rely on TikZ `background` library and hence allow `overlay` option to work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate[shift={(4cm,-3.5cm)}] (Anchor) at (current page.north west);

\only<1>{
\begin{scope}[shift={(Anchor)}] 
\draw[thin,->] (0,0) node (origin) [below] {$0$} -- (0,1) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$};
\draw[thin,->] (-1,0) node (xaxisL) {} -- (1,0) node (xaxisR) [right] {$x$};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
 \draw[fill=red] (-1.1,1.3) rectangle (1.3,-0.3);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}}
%Scope 2... etc
\end{tikzpicture}
```